# Is there a way to install a Xcode 12.x built app on iOS 15 beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

I distributed an app built with Xcode 12.3 on AppCenter and my client, who recently updated to iOS 15 beta, can't install it.
I told him that in order to built for iOS 15 I'd need to build the app using Xcode 13 but, being in beta, I wouldn't be able to submit the app to App Store Connect. (Or at least, it wouldn't pass review)

The client maintains that there's a flag / info field to toggle in order to allow the installation of an Xcode 12.x built application on iOS 15 beta.
He wants that "iOS 15 bypass fix" released, in production.

I asked a few fellow iOS devs about it and the only answer I got was to build with Xcode 13 to provide a test build to the client.

Is there a way to allow the app to install on higher (beta) OS versions than the max deployment target ?

Comment: The problem you're probably running into is the updates they've made on data privacy. I would imagine if you update to latest iOS version it would work on beta. I mean not all of his apps are broken on the beta.. I would just build to the latest available version.